# Xpages File upload control Partial Refresh - Stopped working in Chrome 84 version

Tags: xpages

I was doing a file upload using a fileupload control and partial refresh the panel in onchange event of the fileupload control to load the file into download control. It was working fine in chrome earlier version but chrome 84 version onwards partial refresh is not working, shows blank page. Did any one has this problem, please advise.

here is the source :

```
<xp:panel id="pnlAttachment6">
    <xp:label value="Attachment" id="label60" styleClass=" control-label small" for="xpDocDate_1">  </xp:label>
    <div class="#{javascript:return (getComponent('fileDownload6').getRowCount() == 1 ? 'hidden' : 'visible');}">
        <xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload6" value="#{document1.Body_6}" styleClass="custom-file-input">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pnlAttachment6" disableValidators="true"></xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:fileUpload>
    </div>

    <xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="fileDownload6" displayLastModified="false" value="#{document1.Body_6}" displaySize="false"
        displayType="false" displayCreated="false"
        styleClass="table-borderless" hideWhen="true"
        allowDelete="true" fileNameTitle=" ">
    </xp:fileDownload>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: Please add the code involved

Comment: Added source code

Comment: I’ve had similar reports from 2 users when doing file uploads in Chrome 84. Seen it myself a couple of time, but am unable to reproduce the issue consistently.
Not sure how the process works exactly, but I know that the XPages component uses an iframe to do the partial upload. It might be that Chrome changed something in that area since v84.
For now I’ve recommended the users to use a different browser (e.g. Firefox, Edge Chromium, Brave).